# jquery slideshow only shows the first of several slideshows on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, fadein

I posted this problem under another name a couple of days ago, but working on it some more seems to have helped me narrow down the problem, which is this:

I have a site on which the visitor can click various buttons to reveal a display section with pictures and text related to the tile they click.  However, I want the display to ALSO include a related slideshow rather than just static images.  The problem is, only the FIRST slide show will ever display.  I believe the issue lies somewhere in the jquery fadein script.  It seems like it needs a way to "reset" the fadein function when the user clicks on a different button.  Here is the script and below that the whole page (an abbreviated model...that does work, except for the last two (of three) slide shows.

```
$(function () { /*for the slide show*/
    $ds = $('.fadein div');
    $ds.hide().eq(0).show();
    setInterval(function () {
        $ds.filter(':visible').fadeOut(function () {
            var $div = $(this).next('div');
            if ($div.length === 0) {
                $ds.eq(0).fadeIn();
            } else {
                $div.fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }, 5000); //time
});
```

Here is the whole script: (the fadein is the second function in the script section).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>CSS_TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ccre_theme.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    #displays .hidden {
        /* if any of the items in the id group "displays" group has  the class "hidden", it will not be displayed*/
        display: none;
    }
    #buttons {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
    #displays {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
    </style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { /*for the buttons/displays*/
    window.$ViewItem = $('#displays .default');
    $('#buttons').on('click', 'div', function (e) {
        var $el = $('#displays .' + e.target.className);
        window.$ViewItem.addClass('hidden');
        $el.removeClass('hidden');        
        window.$ViewItem = $el;
    });
});

$(function () { /*for the slide show*/
    $ds = $('.fadein div');
    $ds.hide().eq(0).show();
    setInterval(function () {
        $ds.filter(':visible').fadeOut(function () {
            var $div = $(this).next('div');
            if ($div.length === 0) {
                $ds.eq(0).fadeIn();
            } else {
                $div.fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }, 5000); //time
});
</script> 
 </head>

<body>

<div id="displays">
    <div class="default">This is default content. in a div</div>

    <div class="4 hidden">This is content 4 in a div with slide show
        <div class="fadein">
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1386762_00B.jpg" height="200px" /></div>
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1386637_00B.jpg" height="200px" /></div>
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1385667_00B.jpg" height="200px" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="5 hidden">This is content 5 in a div with slide show
        <div class="fadein">
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1382602_00B.jpg" height="200px" /></div>
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1382108_00B.jpg" height="200px" /></div>
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1381708_00B.jpg" height="200px" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="6 hidden">This is content 6 in a div with slide show
        <div class="fadein">
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1377941_00B.jpg" height="400px" /></div>
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1376861_00B.jpg" height="400px" /></div>
            <div  id="slidebox"><img src="../images/1373099_00B.jpg" height="400px" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>  

</div>

<div id="buttons">
    <div class="4">Show 4 slideshow</div>
    <div class="5">Show 5 slideshow</div>
    <div class="6">Show 6 slideshow</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas for me? Like I said, I think it must need something like a line in the fadein script that will reset that function when the user clicks a different button. Thanks.

Comment: So the problem is it has no way to go from slideshow to slideshow. $ds contains all of the slideshows, but when it finishes the first group (There's no next `div`, so the `if` passes) it resets to the beginning. You should turn on the slideshow for the thing that's active, and turn it off for the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$(function () { /*for the slide show*/
    $ds = $('.fadein div');
    $ds.hide().eq(0).show();
    var slideInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $ds.filter(':visible').fadeOut(function () {
            var $div = $(this).next('div');
            if ($div.length === 0) {
                $ds.eq(0).fadeIn();
            } else {
                $div.fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }, 5000); //time
});

$('.yourButton').click(function () { 
    clearInterval(slideInterval);  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, but it did not appear to alter the page behavior at all. I also tried replacing your fadein script for the original AND placed the clearInterval line into each position of the window.viewItem section and at one of the positions it started to partially work (all pictures for the selected item opened up simultaneously, rather than as a slideshow) so there may be the beginning of a solution here.